# How to customize the look of the crosshair for the iOS Shinobi SDK?

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

I would like to change the crosshair to a single vertical line.  I'm looking for an example of a `SChartCrosshair` subclass that customizes the drawing.  How do I customize the look of the crosshair?

Comment: Do you want to customise the appearance of the crosshair (the horizontal and vertical lines) or the toolip (the view which appears with information about the crosshair)?

Comment: In this case I would like to customize the crosshair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's a few links on the Shinobi site that show you how to customise the crosshair, they might help :)

a) http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/12/04/data-streaming,-crosshairs-and-custom-tooltips-in-shinobicharts/

b) http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2012/07/19/customizing-that-crosshair/

c) http://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols/2013/8/crosshair-with-line-only-to-the-x-axis/

Comment: Thanks.  This forum post is good as well...http://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols/2013/8/crosshair-with-line-only-to-the-x-axis/

Comment: I've added the link to the answer